# Frequency parameter of `ts()` and `findfrequency()` in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Is the result obtained in `findfrequency()` function of forecast package and the frequency parameter of `ts()` the same?

Answer (score 2):

It *probably should be*, but there are no guarantees that it *has to be*.

`findfrequency` will return the *period* with the maximum spectral amplitude of the signal provided as an input. It is relative straight-forward calculation using the results from `spec.ar` where we estimate the spectral density associated with each candidate frequency of a time-series model from auto-regressive fit. Assuming that our raw signal, `x`, having assumed frequency 1, we use it as input to `spec.ar`:

```
specARresults <- spec.ar(x)
```

then then results from `findfrequency` are simply:

```
1 / specARresults$freq[which.max(specARresults$spec)]
```

i.e. the inverse of the frequency having the highest spectral density. And as the inverse of a frequency is a period we get our result. :) (Side-note: Why `findfrequency` returns a period eludes me.)

We can theoretically use this result as input to `ts`'s argument about frequency but we do not *have to*. The frequency  we use to `ts` is probably better to relate to our actual problem. For example, we might have daily expenditure data that happen to have a strong weekly pattern (cause people spend more on weekends). If we do not care for a weekly pattern though, it might be more relevant for us to analyse them assuming a period of 365 days.

Comment: Welcome to the CV community!